# Customize Reminder or Alarm Class in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

is that possible to derive reminder or alarm in windows phone 8 programmatically?

can I customize the reminder sound or alarm sound?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you are stuck with the default sound.